# Android Google authentication Error in Android studio device

Tags: android, firebase, google-signin

Trying to sign in my Android app using Google authentication I have error 12501. I have this error when I run the app in Android studio device, however when I install signed apk in my own mobile, everything works well.
I'm using a new Android client ID signed with Android studio's fingerprint.

Here is my google-services.json oauth_client part :

```
 "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "223...-...j2s5.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 1,
          "android_info": {
            "package_name": "com.example.ucango_2021",
            "certificate_hash": "644d..."
          }
        },
        {
          "client_id": "223...-...esuke.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
```

Request creation method :

```
 // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if exists -> app ->  -> debug -> values -> values.xml.
if yes change. Works for me using map api in debug mode
I hope I helped you
[image]